# CakePHP: self-referencing HABTM associations?

Tags: cakephp, associations

I want to create HABTM self-associations. That is, Users can be associated with other users. The problem is this: I can save associations from one User to another, but I can only view and edit those associations one way. Here's my association:

```
'Partner' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'joinTable' => 'players_trainers',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'player_id',
    'foreignKey' => 'trainer_id', 
    'unique' => true
)
```

So when I call a User (who is a trainer) I can see the players that are associated with them. No sweat. But when trying to view/edit associations from the other end (to see which trainers a player has been associated with) nothing appears, because the association is treating every User the same way: expecting to associate from a trainer, to a player.

I thought about doing an on-the-fly binding in my controller (based on user role) but that seems hacky.

Is there a clean way to have a HABTM self-association, without having to add new fields to my model? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up the other association.

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
 'Partner' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'joinTable' => 'players_trainers',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'player_id',
    'foreignKey' => 'trainer_id', 
    'unique' => true
  ),
  'Trainer' => array(
    'className' => 'User',
    'joinTable' => 'players_trainers',
    'associatedForeignKey' => 'trainer_id',
    'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
    'unique' => true
  )
);
```

Comment: This has 2 problems: a) find('threaded',...) only the "Trainers" but not the "Partners" are returned and 2) adding a Partner via a form doesn't seem to work.